# Inno setup - no compression

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Is it posible to generate a build with inno setup without compression ?

By default it makes setup.exe file that have all files packed inside exe

I want to have a folder with list of my files and setup.exe that will take this files and install on Program Files for user

(I just want to change several files for each user that downloads my program)

Comment: Change those user's specific files with preprocessor and build for each user separate setup. Or use [`external`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#external) flag and include those external files separately from the setup binary. Using of the [`external`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#external) flag is the best solution for your needs.

Comment: Which is it? Inno can do "no compression" while still bundling the files into the executable.

Comment: @Deanna, as I get this question, OP wants to make a unique setup for each user separately, unique in some file(s), e.g. by making a setup which won't be bundled in a single setup binary file.

Comment: @Deanna, I apply the nocompression flag to a .zip file, but the installer still spends 5-6 minutes "compressing" it.....any ideas?

Comment: I see the flag SolidCompression=true was set.  I have set it to false to see if this helps.  My entire payload is a (large) ZIP file, so I don't think I want solid compression enabled.

Comment: oh well, that did not help. If anyone has any other idea, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TLama - thanks **external** flag works for me

solution:

```
Source: "{src}/somefile-or-folder"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable all compression in a setup using the `Compression` directive:

```
[Setup]
Compression = none
```

You can also turn this off for individual files, allowing them to be changed by your downloader with the `nocompression` and `dontverifychecksum` flags.

If you really want to keep the files seperate to the setup package, then you can use the `external` flag and use the `{src}` constant, but then the user will need to download each file individually, or you zip them up.

Comment: I feel this question as how to generate individual setup for each user rather than compression problem.

Comment: @TLama I know, I alluded to that by saying they could update one of the included files, if they have the appropriate flags.